# Find the derivative of this function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$5^{-1/x}$

The answer is $5^{-1/x} \cdot \frac{\ln {5}}{x^2}$

When I solved it, i did not get $\frac{\ln {5}}{x^2}$ but instead, - $\frac{x}{x^2}$

How do I find this correct answer?

(Thanks)

Comment: What is ln/x^2 supposed to mean? Please try to format your question so it is unambiguous. Use parantheses if you don't know LaTeX

Comment: Hint: $5^{-1/x}=e^{-\ln(5)/x}$

Comment: Parentheses, please.  5^-1/x should be read as $\frac{5^{-1}}x=\frac 1{5x}$, but I am sure you mean $5^{\frac {-1}x}$  What is ln/x^2?  That I can't even guess about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By log rules you know that $5^{-1/x} = e^{(-1/x)\ln 5}$, and you can differentiate the right hand side of that equation using the chain rule.

Alternatively, you can use implicit differentiation: $y = 5^{-1/x}$ implies $\ln y = (-1/x)\ln5$, and so $y'/y = (1/x^2)\ln5$. (Finish this.)